# add two datetimes in XSLT 1.0 using grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to add two time as shown below as RunningTime which is in HHMMSS format while grouping on PNo.

```
    <root>
<detail>
<PNo>1</PNo>
<RunningTime>000409</RunningTime>
</detail>
<detail>
<PNo>1</PNo>
<RunningTime>000409</RunningTime>
</detail>
<detail>
<PNo>2</PNo>
<RunningTime>000409</RunningTime>
</detail>
</root>
```

It should be in XSLT 1.0.

XSLT part:

```
<RunningTime><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('program-by-no', PNo)/RunningTime)"/></RunningTime>
```

But this will add time as sum not as Datetime.

Please help.

Comment: you'd have to convert to a plain seconds value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in the course of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), instead of:

```
<RunningTime><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('program-by-no', PNo)/RunningTime)"/></RunningTime>
```

do:

```
<RunningTime>
    <xsl:call-template name="sum-times">
        <xsl:with-param name="times" select="key('program-by-no', PNo)/RunningTime"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</RunningTime>
```

and add the following template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template name="sum-times">
    <xsl:param name="times"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$times">
            <!-- add time as seconds -->
            <xsl:variable name="summand" select="3600 * substring($times[1], 1, 2) + 60 * substring($times[1], 4, 2) + substring($times[1], 7, 2)"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum-times">
                <xsl:with-param name="times" select="$times[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $summand"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- convert seconds to time -->
            <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor($sum div 3600)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor($sum div 60) mod 60"/>
            <xsl:variable name="s" select="$sum mod 60"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($h, '00'), format-number($m, ':00'), format-number($s, ':00'))" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Using your example input, you should see a result similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <program num="1">
      <RunningTime>00:08:18</RunningTime>
   </program>
   <program num="2">
      <RunningTime>00:04:09</RunningTime>
   </program>
</root>
```